# How can the properties of a table be overridden by the properties of the group it belongs to, while designing database schema?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I have a table called Person:
person_id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | group_id | property_id
(group_id will refer to the group_id column of table GroupOfPerson and
property_id will refer to the property_id column of table Property)

And another table called GroupOfPerson:
group_id | group_name | property_id
(property_id will refer to the property_id column of table Property)

And another table called Property:
property_id | property_name

Here, if the Person belongs to GroupOfPerson, the property_id from Person table will be overridden by the property_id from GroupOfPerson table for the corresponding Person. How can this be done effectively done while designing the database schema? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What does this "overridding" mean? E.g.: does a Person't property is always the same as his GroupOfPerson's property?

Comment: @ypercube : It should, but how do you achieve it design wise while designing the database tables?

Comment: If a Person always belongs to a Group and you want that Group's Property to define that Person's property, then you simply remove the `Person.property_id` from the table.

Comment: @ypercube : But what when the Person does not belong to any group? It still needs to have a property which will be only his/her own property. And hence we need the Person.property_id. Well that's how it is designed right now, but any better ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: In that case (where `Person.group_id` can be Null), your design is fine. You can use the `LEFT JOIN / COALESCE()` solution by Raihan.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can define it in the table design level.

However you can enforce it with insert/update triggers on `Person` table. The trigger will copy the value of `property_id` from `GroupOfPerson` table to `Person` table if the `group_id` value is not null in the `Person` table.

Alternately you can do it at the query level. Whenever you select data from `Person` table, join it with `GroupOfPerson` table and select the aprropriate source for `property_id` column based on the null/notnull value in `group_id` column.

Comment: For the alternate solution, you mean to say I can use COALESCE? That sounds good. Actually I was wondering if there is a way to design the schema in such a manner that this can be achieved. But it doesn't seems to be possible at the design level as you suggested. Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs. I am gonna try this and see how effective it is.